# Array appending after each onclick and loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is the code fragment I have tried:

```
radio.onclick = function() {
     var pp = e.target.result.split("\n");
    var pq = pp.split('\n'); 
    var pr = []; // array to append each values

    for (var k = 0; k < pq.length; k++) {
        var a = pq[0];  
    }

    pr = a; // I need to create an array which should append again and again
}
```

In this code, after clicking a radio, a loop generates the value for the 'a' variable, whom it's added to array 'pr'. I want to add the generated value to 'pr' itself **after** the next on-click.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please state what variables exactly represent (e.g. we don't know what pp is) or publish link to jsfiddle.

Comment: Do you realize you are only reading the first index?

Comment: Declare `pr` globally and `var a` outside the `for` loop and 
why you keep assigning same value to `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do this:

```
radio.onclick = function() {
    var pq = pp.split('\n'); 
    var pr = []; // array to append each values

    for (var k = 0; k < pq.length; k++) {
        pr.push(pq[k]);  
    }
}
```

If you need global access to pr just define it outside from radio.onclick.

**Edit**

even shorter:

```
radio.onclick = function() {
    var pq = pp.split('\n');
}
```

or global

```
var pq = [];
radio.onclick = function() {
   pq = pp.split('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just define the array

```
pr
```

globally.

```
var pr = []; // array to append each values

radio.onclick = function() {
 var pq = pp.split('\n'); 


 for (var k = 0; k < pq.length; k++) {
     var a = pq[0];  
 }

 pr.push(a); // i need to create an array which should append again and again
}
```

But there you just get the last `pq[0]`of the loop
Hope that helps

Comment: if this is the right answere, you should not use a loop, better access it directly. `pr.push(pq[0]);`

Comment: And remove that redundant `a`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){var array = new Array(); //Global  declaration
```

radio.onclick = function(){
   //do stuff here..

```
//get your value

array.push(your value);
```

}

});

//if you want to clear the array 
array.splice();